# Is there a way to import vue component from CDN at runtime?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, cdn

Is there a way to import dynamically a vue component from a CDN and load it in a parent component ?
I can easily import modules dynamically when they are in the project folder, but i didn't found solution to load them from a CDN.
And this is not my decision but a task i was asked to do.

Comment: Async components and SystemJS. Make sure `System.import` is ignored by Webpack.

Comment: Please show what have you tried and create a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example